# JavaScript named function auto-invoke

Tags: javascript, function

How can you auto-invoke a named function so you can also call it later?

You can auto-invoke an anonymous function by doing:

```
(function(){
  console.log('called')
})();
```

But if you do

```
(function f(){
  console.log('called')
})();
```

You can not use `f()` later in the code.

Or this (throws error)

```
function f(){
  console.log('called')
}();
```

I know you can declare the `f` and then simply call `f()`, but can you call it right after declaration?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to do. If you're putting it in a closure, then it's going to hide it from everything else. If you want access to it, make a closure and put both the function and the call in it.

Comment: (function() {var f = function() { console.log('foo'); }; f();})(); // the best your gonna get

Comment: Why doesn't make sense? I want to declare for a javascript game a `draw` function (the game loop) which is a recursive function (calls itself with requestAnimFrame) and I have to call it the first time (in order to enter the recursion).

Comment: To make it clear, I know that this can be done as I did in my last example very easily, but I just wanted to know if you can auto-invoke a named function the same way you can do with an anonymous function.

Comment: It doesn't make sense because closures are used to restrict access to functionality. As I said, put them both in a closure as in the answer below.

Comment: Yeah, but that is not auto-invoking, that's just calling the function after it was declared. So, I want to do something like `function f(){
  console.log('called')
}();` . Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Those two are functionally the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to what you want :
First of all, you definitely should use your third proposition, it's clearer and what's more important : it does not create a closure when it's not required.

Anyway, if you want to execute a function AND name it, you should register it to your current scope (the default one is the window object)

Here is an example :

```
(window.myFunction = function(){
    alert("myFunction called")
})(); //triggers the function

window.myFunction() ; //triggers the function
myFunction() ; //triggers the function as well
```

Comment: This is a great answer, as I can also extend this to my problem :) (declare the auto-invoking function as a member of an object).

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here, but how about:

```
var f = (function (){
    function f() {
        console.log('called');
    }
    f();
    return f;
})();

f();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LXEm6/

You define `f` inside the closure and invoke it, and then return it and assign it to a variable so you can use it again later.

I'm not necessarily suggesting this is a *good* pattern, but without knowing more about the specific problem you are trying to solve.

It seems like it would be much simpler to just do something like this:

```
function f() {
    console.log('called');
}

(function() {
    f();    // calls f immediately
})();

// and later on:
f();
```

Another edit: Okay, here's a really horrible solution that would also work if not in strict mode (which is reason enough not to use it):

```
var f = (function f() { 
    console.log("called");
    return arguments.callee;
}())

f();
```

It's a slightly more compact version of the first solution.

Comment: The idea is that I want to code less, not more :). I just want to do `function f(){   console.log('called') }();` . Why doesn't this work?

Comment: @Cristy: Because that's not how function expressions work. It's only a couple of extra lines.

Comment: I would keep away from the first example & stick with the much preferred second, having multiple instances of a variable in different scopes is just, difficult.

Comment: @MackieeE: absolutely agree. At the very least I'd not have the variable named the same as the function inside the closure. It's just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
(function() {
    var f = window.f = function() { // defining f variable like inside a closure but also as a global to be invoked from everywhere
        console.log("SOMETHING");
    };

    f(); // funciton will be invoked
})();

f(); // function will be invoked as well
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GtBBa/)

Comment: f wont be defined outside of the scope of the closure. (ah theres the fix)

Comment: @Gauthier It is, you can try

Comment: The idea is that I want to code less, not more :). I just want to do `function f(){   console.log('called') }();` . Why doesn't this work?

Comment: @Cristy If you want that it worked in global environment don't define it inside a closure

Comment: It is not inside a closure. But it doesn't work: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: @Cristy It doesn't work because `JavaScript` syntax is not correct, you have to define it without `()`, it is simple as that